# How to capture log for MYSQL event scheduler

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL. I have one event scheduler for every 1 hour. Can we create log for every call when it was started and when it was finished and the status (success or failure).
Pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the errors with

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
```

or you can use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` which is available in MySQL 5.6.4

Make a log table and insert timestamps and error returned by handler